# Increase swap space for RAM

Tags: swap

I have Micromax canvas 2.2 with android 4.2.2 & kernel version 3.4.5. I have already rooted my phone. Now, to increase swap space I partitioned sd card using mini partition. Then tried to link it using Link2sd app. But it didn't work. Everytime I try to mount that partition phone restarts but the effect is gone after restarting. Means nothing actually happens. 
Please help.